# #defines in stdafx.h not being found, I have to copy-paste them into each file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

### stringize.h:

```
#ifndef STRINGIZE_H
#define STRINGIZE_H

#define _STR2(x) #x
#define _STR1(x) _STR2(x)
#define _WARN __FILE__ "("_STR1(__LINE__)") : Warning : "
#define _TODO __FILE__ "("_STR1(__LINE__)") : TODO : "

#endif// STRINGIZE_H
```

If I `#include` this file in my .cpp, all works fine. But if I include it in stdafx.h, and then include stdafx.h in my.cpp file, these defines are not known:

### SomeFile.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#pragma message(_TODO"test")
```

> warning C4083: expected 'string'; found identifier '_TODO'

We use `#ifndef` and `#pragma once` guards but isn't the point of putting `"include stdafx.h` at the start of every cpp file exactly to save me doing it manually? We do have "Use precompiled headers" *enabled*.

Comment: Are you using precompied headers, through stdafx.h ?

Comment: Yes. But I thought they made the contents available globally - did I misunderstand the point of them?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of stdafx.h? The purpose of pre-compiled headers is to reduce compile time through a reduction in the number of `#include` pre-processing directives that need to be processed.

Comment: @John I don't know what you mean by that. However precompiled headers with MSVC have a few limitations, and in my experience bugs and inconsistencies. So there are 2 things you should try: 1. Do a Rebuild All. 2. Disable precompiled headers. If any of those resolves the issue you have, it's an issue with using precompiled headers. If not, there's something else going on, so please post your stdafx.h

Comment: It's business specific so I cannot. But given that `#include <Stringize.h> is the last line and is not inside any `#ifdef' block, it surely must be being (pre-)processed or we'd see much bigger issues!

Comment: @nos you're saying a limitation of predefine headers is you can't use them to list include files you want to be available to every .cpp file? I thought that was pretty much the _point_... but I'll try rebuilding.

Comment: AHA! Rebuilding worked. If you would like to suggest as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, you have to rebuild. The whole idea of precompiled headers is that they're compiled once ahead of time because they don't change very often. When you change them, you need to recompile and regenerate the precompiled header.

Comment: @CodyGray Presumably the VS build system should detect that and rebuild it. Which it sometimes does. And sometimes not. It's rather buggy in my experience.